# can I dynamically set the template in angular.js routes?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know if it's possible to dynamically construct the templateUrl string used in the routeProvider, with access to the route variables. I want to something like the following, which does not work obviously but should give you an idea of what I wish I could do:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/:pathFrag', {
      templateUrl: getTemplateUrl( pathFrag ),  // some callable with access to pathFrag
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
```

thanks!

Comment: should just be `templateUrl: getTemplateUrl` (pass function as reference) then first argument will be the path params

Answer (score 0):

Check the page of [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider)

and from the docs...

> templateUrl – {string=|function()=} – path or function that returns a
>   path to an html template that should be used by ngView.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/:pathFrag', {
      templateUrl: function(pathFrag){
                    //write your code...

                return tempUrl;  //return the required path for file
            },

      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
```